# Matlab trailing singleton dimension

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, dimensions, trailing

I have the following code

```
o = ones(4,3,2)
c = cellfun(@squeeze,num2cell(o,[2 3]), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

which gives as expected the 4 cells, each containing 3x2 matrixes.

But if I reduce the last dimension of o to one, the behavior is totally not as expected:

```
o = ones(4,3,1)
c = cellfun(@squeeze,num2cell(o,[2 3]), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

The output is:

```
[1x3 double]
[1x3 double]
[1x3 double]
[1x3 double]
```

Whereas I would expect:

```
[3x1 double]
[3x1 double]
[3x1 double]
[3x1 double]
```

Any possiblity how to obtain the correct result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the dimension of `o` is `4 x 3 x 1`, `num2cell(o, [2 3])` gives a `1 x 3` vector. As stated in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html), `squeeze` has no effect on a 2D array, so it will remain a row or column vector:

> Two-dimensional arrays are unaffected by squeeze; if `A` is a row or column vector or a scalar (1-by-1) value, then `B = A`.

```
size(squeeze(rand(1, 3)))
%   1   3

size(squeeze(rand(3, 1)))
%   3   1
```

As pointed out by [@Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577170/matlab-trailing-singleton-dimension/39577233#comment66464386_39577233), you could replace `squeeze` with `permute` to get the dimensions you'd expect.

```
c = cellfun(@(x)permute(x, [2 3 1]), num2cell(o,[2 3]), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Comment: ... so the solution would be to replace `@squeeze` by `@(x)permute(x,[2 3 1])`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for that!